# Calculate total number of hours each employ worked per day at two shift in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to calculate total number of hours each employ worked per day at two shift in excel.
For example on day shift 1/02/2023 employ card no V2605 if has 2 entries login and 1 entries logout. I want to select only first one login time 1/02/2023 08:01 and last one log out time of that particular employ entry 1/02/2023 20:03. Now I calculate total hours worked for that day.
Also same as in night shift. Example card no V2635
Calculate total number of hours each employ worked per day at two shift in excel.

Calculate total number of hours each employ worked per day at both shift in excel.

[manual calculetion](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c_AGplIYasRzdZSytNF1P7b7YZ7w59uN/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113495340063347455622&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. This is a site where you can ger help with a specific problem, such as an error or a formula that doesn't work. It sounds like you want someone to do your work for you. What you need to do is post details of what have tried so far, the specific problem you have encountered.

Comment: I am not asking anyone to do my work, I am asking for help with a formula in Excel, I have given total details in a sheet of Excel, I am asking for a formula. I have done my work with manual calculation  I just want excel formula for that.

Comment: ok but you should paste your question so that people dont have to go to an external site (its part of the rules. If you search for it you will see why). You should use =MINIFS() to find the start time and MAXIFS() to find the end time. So in cell L6 have `=MINIFS($C:$C, $B:$B, L$5, $D:$D, $K6) ` and in L7 have `=MAXIFS($C:$C, $B:$B, L$5, $D:$D, $K7) `

Comment: BTW I didnt downvote you, but it will be downvoted because it is a low quality question because you didnt put any code or formulas in your question

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `=L7-L6` in the cell `L8`. It might say 0.51, but you can change the formatting of the cell to be a time and will then say 12:07:43.

Comment: But my question is how I put data in L7,L8,L10,L11,L13,L14 etc. from Row Data? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C8Jic7TnwbCRVdku8dWUfUPTgGRxhAaa/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=113495340063347455622&rtpof=true&sd=true

Answer (score 0):

### Lookup Data

In cell `L6`, try:

```
=IFERROR(TAKE(FILTER($C$2:$C$35,($A$2:$A$35=IF($K6="IN",$J6,$J5))*($B$2:$B$35=L$5)*($D$2:$D$35=$K6)),IF($K6="IN",1,-1)),"")
```

and copy across.

If you put the data in an Excel table you could use:

```
=IFERROR(TAKE(FILTER(Table1[and Time],(Table1[Card]=IF($K12="IN",$J12,$J11))*(Table1[Punch Date]=L$5)*(Table1[Type]=$K12)),IF($K12="IN",1,-1)),"")
```

to make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a helper column combining the "CARD","DATE" and "TYPE" otherwise, you can just combine the column ranges i.e. A:A&B:B&D:D. I'd create helper column for readability.  [Check this  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cgtu.png).

Then the data has two problem.

1. Only get the final "OUT"
2. If the shift ended the next day, add a 1 day to OUT to compute the total start and end shift.

We will only use INDEX MATCH + COUNTIFS

> =L$6+ INDEX($C$3:$C$36,MATCH($J7&L$6&$K7,$G$3:$G$36,0))

- L$6 is the date. Use the helper column to get the first match or the LogIN.

Solution for #1:

> +(COUNTIFS($G$3:$G$36,$J14&L$6&$K14)-1)

- Count the instances of OUT then add the value to INDEX:MATCH result to move to next row.

Solution for #2:

> IF IN > OUT then Add 1 day to date.

[Login Logout Computation SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tX4Z.png)